# having problems with my router guardian when re-load my web app

Tags: vuex, vue-router, router

I'm building this one-page web application and now I'm working on guardians of my router in order to watch authenticated users.

I guess it is working semi-ok because cause the global property I set referring to redirect the non-user to a welcome page does the work indeed, but ignore the condition, here the JS file container of it:

```
 import store from '../store/index'
 export default(to,from,next)=>{
  if (store.getters.getUser){
      next()
  }else{
      next('/welcome')
  }

}
```

where in that conditionant refers to an already declared getter in vuex with which expose if user is logged in or not, thus in the opposite case (user not logged)automatically visitor would be redirected  to a welcome page.

In my router file is the following :

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    beforeEnter:routerGuard
  },
  {
    path: '/results/:idItemSelected',
    name: 'SearchResults',
    component:SearchResults,
    props:true,
    
  },
  {
    path: '/welcome',
    name: 'WelcomingPage',
    component:WelcomingPage
  },
  {
    path: '/signUp',
    name: 'SignUpPage',
    component:SignUpPage
  },
  {
    path: '/signIn',
    name: 'SignInPage',
    component:SignInPage
  }

]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

my logic hints to me only set the guard in the home('/') page because from there is where all elements in the app initialize, but when in log my user and go to any other component in the app and by-chance I do reload the page , again throws me to the welcome page being already logged

Answer (score 0):

I guess using beforeEach:routerGuard, the problem gets repaired.
Any way I would appreciate other ideas referring to this in order to have in mind for future projects.